# Payflow Pro get the list of transaction made by customer

Tags: payflowpro

I need to get the list of transaction made for the customer. It should include both settled and unsettled transaction. I am having the following parameters such as reference transaction ID, name, email. Is there possibility to achieve it?

Comment: Please tell us what you have already tried.  Presumably you are hitting a Payflow webservice to get this information; what methods are you calling and what responses are you getting?

Comment: I am using PayflowPro SDK for processing the customer. It doesn't have much calls to process or retreive the details. Even if we use TRXTYPE = I (Inquiry) it only retrives particular transaction detail only. But I want all the transaction made for the customer